# Как мне получить объект message в telegram?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Я использую `telebot` в `Python`, но вы можете дать совет, основываясь на любой библиотеке. Задача следующая: есть бот, которому даны права админа в канале N, и требуется получить содержимое определенной публикации (id сообщения мне известно) на этом канале, чтобы эти данные отредактировать и сохранить обновленное сообщение. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как именно можно получить содержимое определенного сообщения, именно как объект `telebot.types.Message`, т.к. мне необходимо будет редактировать также встроенные ссылки и кнопки. Заранее огромное спасибо за помощь!